# BroadcastReceiver camera doesnt work for videos

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello I have CameraListener I need onReceive to occur each time a photo or video is taken. I tried this code. It works well for photos, but it doesnt do anything when video is taken.

```
public class CameraListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".camera.CameraListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I also tried using more actions in intent. But it only caused onReceive to occur multiple times when 1 photo was taken and still didnt change anything for videos.

Comment: "It works well for photos" -- not really. Few camera apps will send that broadcast.

Comment: CommonsWare: So do you have some better solution how to make this work?

Comment: You have no way of reliably monitoring photos and videos taken by arbitrary other apps. Either request those yourself (e.g., `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) or implement your own camera app.